# How to fix twisted.internet.error.FileDescriptorOverrun Error

Tags: python, networking, twisted, file-descriptor, unix-socket

Using twisted transferring socket connection (self.transport.fileno() ) file descriptor to the client over the UNIX domain socket. It is working great for the first file descriptor sent but for the second file descriptor getting the following error

`twisted.internet.error.FileDescriptorOverrun`

According to the documentation [FileDescriptorOverrun](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-22.4.0/api/twisted.internet.error.FileDescriptorOverrun.html)  it says if at any point fewer bytes have been written than file descriptors have been sent, the connection is closed with this exception.  **What does it mean** ?

An example on sending and receiving file descriptor over the UNIX domain socket is as follows

[sendfd.py](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-20.3.0/_downloads/04e2101b7e73dcb8b40fa3abb7bd4cf0/sendfd.py)
[recvfd.py](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-20.3.0/_downloads/c0f75533edf0fc24c1f1a6394183ca3e/recvfd.py)